# generic custom equals check for structs

Tags: rust

I want to compare 2 structs (`lhs` and `rhs`) of the same type but with a custom logic.
If a property of the `lhs` has `None` as value, we skip the check of this property. If `lhs` has `Some` we compare it and if the value is a struct, we need to use the same logic for nested structs.

**Example**

These 2 structs should be treated as "don't differ".

```rust
let lhs = super::RepositoryResponse {
    full_name: "foo/bar".into(),
    security_and_analysis: Some(super::SecurityAndAnalysisResponse {
        secret_scanning: Some(super::SecurityAndAnalysisStatusResponse {
            status: super::Status::Enabled,
        }),
        secret_scanning_push_protection: None,
        dependabot_security_updates: None,
        secret_scanning_validity_checks: None,
    }),
    delete_branch_on_merge: Some(true),
    allow_auto_merge: None,
    allow_squash_merge: None,
    allow_merge_commit: None,
    allow_rebase_merge: None,
    allow_update_branch: None,
};
let rhs = super::RepositoryResponse {
    full_name: "foo/bar".into(),
    security_and_analysis: Some(super::SecurityAndAnalysisResponse {
        secret_scanning: Some(super::SecurityAndAnalysisStatusResponse {
            status: super::Status::Enabled,
        }),
        secret_scanning_push_protection: Some(super::SecurityAndAnalysisStatusResponse {
            status: super::Status::Enabled,
        }),
        dependabot_security_updates: Some(super::SecurityAndAnalysisStatusResponse {
            status: super::Status::Enabled,
        }),
        secret_scanning_validity_checks: Some(super::SecurityAndAnalysisStatusResponse {
            status: super::Status::Enabled,
        }),
    }),
    delete_branch_on_merge: Some(true),
    allow_auto_merge: Some(true),
    allow_squash_merge: Some(true),
    allow_merge_commit: Some(true),
    allow_rebase_merge: Some(true),
    allow_update_branch: Some(true),
};
assert_eq!(false, lhs.differ(&rhs));
```

Is there a generic solution (maybe with reflection) to do this?

Comment: Are the fields of `rhs` guaranteed always to be `Some`, or might they sometimes be `None`?

Comment: This would typically be done with macros. There is no such thing as introspection in Rust. Also, I would suggest naming the property of two such structs "being compatible" rather than "being equal" as this relation is not transitive.

Comment: @eggyal it could also be that the `rhs` is `None`

Comment: @jthulhu it’s not „being compatible“. We always talk about the same struct. `lhs` is my requested state and `rhs` the actual state. And only if the spec is Some I need to compare it with the actual setting. So that I don’t need to send update requests